# Output the total number of rows in a view

Tags: 7, views

Does anyone know how to show the count of the results of a custom view?

Comment: In the footer, for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom section to either the header or footer to do this.

- Edit the view / display.
- In the center section, click **Add** next to **Header** or **Footer**.
- Choose **Global: Result Summary**.  Add it where you need it.
- Then, edit the textarea to be the format that you need.  There are a bunch of tokens available for building up the numbers.
- Preview the view, and then **Save** if everything is OK.